# Is it possible to bulk add meta fields to all products in Shopify?

Tags: shopify

I'm working on customizing a Shopify theme where i need to somehow add custom metafields to all products (preferably not manually). More like it would work in Wordpress using ACF. Is this possible? I'm currently using https://apps.shopify.com/metafields-manager-by-hulkapps.

Comment: No. Each metafield has it's own endpoint. You'll have to use API to do for high numbers.

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply. I guess I have to go another route.

Comment: @HymnZ Lets say i'll add the meta fields manually. Can they be named the same?

Comment: Like

product 1 -> my_meta
product 2 -> my_meta

Comment: Yes. Absolutely.

Comment: Doesn't your app take care of bulk metafields?

Comment: No, i need to edit each product separately. I'ts a project i've taken over.

Comment: Yeah, there are better metafield-editing apps out there, including ones that can let you import spreadsheets to do your heavy lifting for you.  The only downside of course is that the more powerful apps typically have a slightly higher subscription fee - but if you're relying on having the fields, they're definitely worth it

Answer (score 0):

Adding Metafield resources to Shopify products is supported using the Shopify API. They offer both a conventional Rest API as you'd find with most other web platforms, as well as a GraphQL API that is considered more modern and efficient by some. Assuming your Metafield data is per-product, you would iterate through that data on a per product basis, create a metafield resource to support it, and attach that resource to the product in question. One of the very simplest of tasks with an API.